# Text-editors in eclipse/matlab loses focus occasionally after upgrading to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, eclipse, matlab, text-editor, focus

This is a question asked on stackoverflow, and someone there recommends me to move the question here. My problem is that, I have just upgraded from Ubuntu 10.04 to 12.04.3 LTS. An annoying thing is that, in eclipse and matlab, the text editor loses focus sometimes. The detailed phenomena are as follows:

Eclipse

1. Happens after using auto-completion (activated by customized shortcut `alt+/`), or switching from other windows, or pressing `ctrl+z`, etc.
2. Can use mouse to move cursor around, but keyboard does not respond.
3. Using `alt-tab` to switch back and forth, or click some other parts of the window and click the text field again, can solve the problem.

And similar things are happening in matlab, whenever I hit `tab`. But `gedit` and browsers are working fine. I've looked around and tried to disable all kinds of related system shortcuts (such as `alt` for dashboard popup), and login with gnome classic/ubuntu2d/etc, but none of them solve the problem. Wonder if anyone knows how to get around of it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem and now I understood why this is a problem that only a limited number of people encountered.

So the problem is that I was using SCIM for keyboard input in previous versions of ubuntu, which is out of date and has conflict with many java programs in ubuntu 12.04. As I removed it and switched to iBUS based input method everything works great.

Hope this helps.